# Using a filter on a dimension/metric in Google Analytics embedded api code

Tags: filter, embed, analytics, dimension, metric

var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:pageviews',
      dimensions: 'ga:pageTitle',
      filters: 'ga:pageTitle =~ %5ELecture\s.*',
      'start-date': '30daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'COLUMN',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  });

Above is the code that google embed api gave me for a quick dashboard as shown  in the "embed code api tutorial" on google's analytics website. This simple dashboard is enough for what I desire to be shown on my website, however, after fetching the data I have to filter some of it... Specifically, the "dimension". According to the following link, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataReferenceDataFeed,
the syntax for filtering a metric or dimension is shown. However, this isn't not returning any chart onto my website, and so I believe the syntax to be wrong. When I remove the line of code beginning with "filters:", a chart is displayed according to the prescribed metrics and dimensions simply without any filter...

Where am I going wrong with the syntax for the filter?

I have tried many different possibilities, including URL encoded characters as opposed to ga's syntax... Any help is appreciated, thank you!